# vue js dynamic filter names in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have a nested `v-for` in my html, and in every iteration I need to apply filter. The filter itself is the same, but it should work only in current iteration.

For now, my `v-for` looks like this (it's also Laravel Blade templating, that's why I need these `@`):

```
<div class="col s4" v-for="(ind, campaign) in campaigns">
    <select class="select-class" v-model="tags_filter_@{{ind}}" multiple style="height: 150px;">
        <option value="">all</option>
        <option v-for="tag in tags" value="@{{tag.title}}">@{{tag.title}}</option>
    </select>

    <select v-model="campaign.selectedWebsites" multiple class="mdc-select__surface select-class" style="height: 300px;" id="web_select_@{{ind}}">
        <option v-for="(index, website) in websites | filterBy tags_filter_@{{ind}}" id="website_@{{ind}}_@{{website.id}}" value="@{{website.id}}">@{{website.url}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And it doesn't work. **I need websites in each campaign to be filtered by their own tag select**. But if I remove `_@{{ind}}` from `v-model` and `filterBy`, logically it becomes the same model everywhere, and works on all iterations at the same time.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed @{{ind}} to [ind] in v-model and filterBy, and it worked out.